# How to get rid of the original yticks/yticklabels when I use ax.set_yscale('log')

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some values in a semilogy plot. I need to use the

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

rather than

```
ax.semilogy(...
```

because i have some arrays with negative values (so I can set the scale to symlog).

My code

```
ax = plt.subplot(132)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.plot(np.arange(0,4),array,'-o')
ax.errorbar(np.arange(0,4),array,yerr=[yerr_neg,yerr_pos])
ax.set_yticks(np.exp(np.arange(-0.4,0.5,0.1)))
ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(-0.4,0.5,0.1))
```

however the automatically placed ticks and labels are still there:

[image: figure with plot]

how do I properly get rid of the original ticks/labels? I get still the same error by eliminating either plot line (meaning deleting the ax.plot line or the ax.errorbar line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels shown are minor ticklabels. You may set the minor ticks to an empty list to get rid of them.

```
ax.set_yticks([], minor=True)
```

or just set the minor ticks off,

```
ax.minorticks_off()
```